# Some areas inside the Vuetify Dialog box don't close it even if there is no content there

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuetify.js, vue-directives

See this image here of my custom Lightbox component.

[image]

One should be able to simply exit the component and go back to the page by clicking on anywhere outside the image or the `v-sheet` component on the right (which by the way, is *supposed* to be touching the image, but I can't figure out how to move it without using margin).

Unfortunately, the red boxes exist - they are areas where clicking *should* close the dialog, but don't. This is because the entire Dialog component is the green box - it believes even those red boxed areas are part of the component.

I've been attempting to use `@click` and `v-click-outside` directives where possible to try and exclude the image and the sheet component can be clicked but everything else closes the dialog, but unfortunately I only get strange behaviors that donn't help at all.

Also, I found out using `margin: auto` will create another unclickable area, so I need to find out another way to move it over.

[Source Code](https://gist.github.com/8c932733097b60c30771130172bad9bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1:

> "is supposed to be touching the image, but I can't figure out how to move it without using margin"

Instead of `lg="10"` on the first col, you can use `lg="auto"` so it will shrink to fit its contents.

```
          justify="center"
          class="fill-height"
        >
          <v-col
-           lg="10"
+           lg="auto"
            md="12"
            offset-lg="0"
            class="fill-height text-right"
          >
```

### Problem 2:

> "areas where clicking should close the dialog, but don't"

You can use `pointer-events: none` on the dialog body to disable click event capturing, then `pointer-events: auto` on specific elements to selectively enable it.

```
          <v-col
            lg="2"
            md="4"
            align-self="top"
-           @click="dialog = false"
          >
            <v-sheet
              class="rounded-tr-lg text-left"

...

- <style lang="scss">
- .v-dialog {
+ <style lang="scss" scoped>
+ ::v-deep .v-dialog {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    box-shadow: none !important;
+   pointer-events: none;
+ }
+ .v-image,
+ .v-btn,
+ .v-sheet {
+   pointer-events: auto;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Use flexbox and @click function to close whatever

Basically, if you get your css to do a similar layout, but fill those red boxes with a `background: blue` you in turn can put an @click on that same div, which will close whatever you need.

## Option 2: Use Modals

I would use a parent component that communicates to an "image component" and "image details component" (such that the two components are siblings.

Moreover, I would personally use v--modal for both of these sibling components, and have the `closed` event tied to a single instance of closing both modals by names

The `shiftX` and `shiftY` should be enough for placement.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal